# WCF via IIS problem IP address

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I made a WCF Service on Duplex Protocol.
It's works correctly and fine. But I have only one small problem:

here is a IP string where can I start an test it:
http://localhost:5659/Service.svc

But when I choose my real IP address on my local machine (where localhost existed):
http://93.4.18.3:5659/Service.svc

I can't connet yet. Also I can't connect from other addresses using my real IP address.
May be something wrong in my web.config ?

Btw - my firewall if switched off.

Here is my config:

```
<extensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="pollingDuplex" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.PollingDuplexElement, System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GameStreamServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="pollingDuplexBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <pollingDuplex maxPendingSessions="2147483647" maxPendingMessagesPerSession="2147483647" inactivityTimeout="02:00:00" serverPollTimeout="00:05:00" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WcfServer.Service" behaviorConfiguration="GameStreamServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="pollingDuplexBinding" contract="WcfServer.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: How's the HTTP binding for that site in IIS configured?

Comment: this is all file with config.  Where should I find HTTP binding ?

Comment: In IIS Manager: right-click on the site this service is hosted in, select "Edit Bindings...", and see what it says for HTTP, especially the "IP Address" column.

Comment: Oh super ! ServiceGuy. You can write an answer and I gonna do +1 for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Site bindings in IIS. It is possible that the HTTP binding on port 5659 is configured for a specific host header ("localhost") or a specific IP address (not 93.4.18.3) only. That would explain the behavior you're getting.